# How to install a NodeJS package from a github repo

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to install a package from a github repo but I get the following message:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/z0019rb/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/node" "/Users/z0019rb/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/target-digital-design-tokens
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 'target-digital-design-tokens' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'target-base-pattern-library'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/z0019rb/dev/design-systems/designsystems-site/npm-debug.log
```

And this is what my package.json looks like:

```
"target-digital-design-tokens": "git+ssh://git@git.target.com:design-systems/design-tokens.git"
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. The repo which I'm trying to install has a package.json. Thanks!

Comment: what command are you using to install? The package.json entry looks fine.

Comment: Did you try it using https only? eg. npm install https://git.target.com/design-systems/design-tokens.git
I think it's an issue with the source, which cannot be accessed

Comment: Wild guess: try a `/` instead of a `:` after `git.target.com`?

Comment: I'm doing `npm install` to install. I tried using https but it doesn't work. I've tried all these options.

Comment: The strangest thing is even after removing this package from package.json, npm tries to install it but it has no reference in my package.json file. How can it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead                           :

```
"git+https://target.com/design-systems/design-tokens"
```

and don't forget to set git repo in your package.json like so :

```
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
     "url": "git@target.com:design-systems/design-tokens.git"
 },
```

If the git server is behind a proxy don't forget to set env `http_proxy` before `npm install` something like this :

```
npm config set proxy "http://domain......@myproxy:8080"
npm config set https-proxy "http://domain......@myproxy:8080"
```

Comment: That doesn't' seem to work. The interesting thing is it used to work before and I didn't change anything.